# Batch Printing TIFF Files in Windows

Tags: windows, batch, printing, printer, tiff

I am trying to batch print .TIFF files efficiently.  I have found that I can drag files from windows into the print job queue window and it will print them right from there.

With PDF's of varying paper sizes and MS Office docs, they print properly.  However, TIFF files always come out with the edges cut off.  It seems to be setting the "scale" of the TIFF to 100%, and centering it on the page.

What I would like is for it to default to "Fit to Page" or "Best Fit" or something along those lines.

I had considered that windows might be using the default program set to open the file to print with, but changing the default program doesn't change the output.

I'm at a loss on how to get this to work, although I'm pretty sure that it is possible.  Somewhere Windows is pulling up a program to print these and that program likely has changeable settings.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will do "fit to page" but Irfanview can batch print any supported image from the command-line:

`i_view32.exe c:\foldername\*.tif /print`

Will print all the files with extension .tif found in the `foldername` directory/folder and then close IrfanView. Haven't tested multipage TIFF. You can send the print job to a different printer by providing a name after print, as such: `/print="Name of the printer"`

See `i_options.txt` for all available command-line parameters. Remember: IrfanView is case-sensitive!

Answer (score 0):

Further to @JSanchez's answer, Irfanview can also do the job without using a command line, as follows:

Start Irfanview and click the Thumbnails tool.
In Thumbnails, open the folder with the images.
Select the images you want (using Shift and Ctrl keys to select multiple images)
Go to File > Print selected files as single images
Tick the button "Best fit to page"
Click Print

Note: the "Best fit to page" setting will be remembered for the next print job, so it will also be used if you use JSanchez's command line suggestion.

Another thought: if you set Irfanview as the default program for handling images (something I recommend regardless) it should then work if you drop the TIFFs onto the print queue.

Irfanview can be downloaded [here](http://www.irfanview.com/). It's a great tool that I use all the time.

Comment: @user3272756 Did either of the answers satisfy you?